# Google cloud micro Instance not FREE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an app deployed in a Google cloud micro instance which should be free, but it charges me extra..

How can I check why it is charging me, so I can fix it and use the micro instance as a free tier service..

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of information on your instance(s), but I would suggest consulting this doc[1], especially in the [Always Free usage limits] to see if your project still matches what's restricted for micro instances to always be free.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier?hl=en_US&_ga=2.238739397.-453584049.1567518825#always-free

Comment: Hi, I have seen  that link, , but where can I check which of these limits i have exceeded ? So I can change my code to not exceed those limits..

Comment: Can anyone help please??

Answer (score 0):

You can ceck it in the Billing page. There is the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports) to do it.

You can check the Allways Free products [here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier?hl=en_US&_ga=2.238739397.-453584049.1567518825#always-free-usage-limits).

Comment: I know these links. But where can I see what I am spending?? For example , all day I see it is 0.00 spent up to 23:59, then it charges me... Why this happens?? As I commented to the other answer, where to check what limits I have exceeded from the Always free..

Comment: In your Google Console go to the Billing section. Then select the Reports option in the side bar menu.  Using the filters you can select _Group by_  Product  or SKU and the cost of every product and what are you spending.